# sockaddr_in not found in XCode 6 (on OS X 10.10 Yosemite)

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to send UDP packets from an objective c app. It's been working fine since OS X 10.6 until Yosemite came along. Now i'm getting "unknown type name 'sockaddr_in'" error.

my code:

```
#import <sys/socket.h>
-(void)sendUdpPacket:(unsigned int) udp_address port:(unsigned short)port data:(const char*)data dataSize:(long)dataSize
{
    int handle = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );

    if ( handle <= -1 )
    {
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( udp_address );

    address.sin_port = htons( port );
    if ( bind( handle, (const sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) ) < -1 )
    {
        printf( "-----------------------failed to bind socket\n " );
        return;
    }
    int nonBlocking = 1;
    if ( fcntl( handle, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK, nonBlocking ) == -1 )
    {
        printf( "----------------------failed to set non-blocking socket for %d\n", port );
        return;
    }

    int sent_bytes = sendto( handle, data, dataSize, 0, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) );
    close(handle);
}
```

now i'm getting errors that it can't find `IPROTO_UDP or sockaddr_in`

has anyone come across this problem?

EDIT: didn't realize that stuff in <> brackets wasn't displaying

Comment: Did you also install the Xcode command line tools? If not, there are probably no header files in `/usr/include` et al.  Try running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Show all your include files.

Comment: @NedDeily yes, i have CL tools installed, i tried running that command just in case, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [inet(4) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/inet.4.html). You have to:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

In general, the socket interface is generic. It can be used with different address families. The `struct sockaddr` is a general form, while `sockaddr_in` is specific to IPv4. You would use `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6 addresses. For Unix domain sockets, you would use `sockaddr_un`. Etc. You need to consult the man page for the type of socket you want to work with (e.g. [inet6(4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/inet6.4.html), [unix(4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/unix.4.html), etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6 needs the complete data type definition. Not "`sockaddr_in`" but "`struct sockaddr_in`". The same for "`const sockaddr*`" must be "`const struct sockaddr*`".